# Extract certain values from a for loop

Tags: python, database, request

I have a for loop which prints values between 3 and 42.5, however, I want to assign a variable to only a certain range of values in this case between 1 and 8.

```py
with requests.Session() as s:
  r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
  sizes = soup.findAll(True,{'class':'product__sizes-size-1'})
  for allsize in sizes:
    print(allsize.text)
```

Where this outputs `3 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 8 36 37.5 38 38.5 39 40 40.5 41 42.5`

How would I assign a variable to only the values which are between 1 and 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
  r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
  sizes = [item for item in soup.findAll(True,{'class':'product__sizes-size-1'}) if float(item.text) >=1 and float(item.text) <=8]
  
  for allsize in sizes:
    print(allsize.text)
```

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark the answer as correct :)